# How to publish a post on wordpress, the post is already published on Blogger.com

Tags: wordpress, blogger

I have a [blog](http://www.jaagdeveloper.com/)

, I want to share/post some of the articles from this blog to my WordPress [website](https://vacancyindex.com). Is there anyway?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about cross-posting in existing software, not about programming.

Comment: I am not cross-posting in existing software. There are also some plugins available to achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve that by Javascript and [Blogger JSON API](https://developers.google.com/blogger/docs/2.0/json/getting_started).

The following example shows the last post title from your blogger blog

```
<div id="content"></div>

<script>
    function get(json) {

        document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = "<h2>" + json.feed.entry[0].title.$t + "</h2>";
    }
</script>

<script src="your-blog-url/feeds/posts/default?alt=json-in-script&callback=get"></script>
```